# Combinations problem on committee.

Tags: combinatorics

A committee of three boys and three girls is to be selected from a class of 14 boys and 17 girls. In how many ways can the committee be selected if:
(a) Ana has to be on the committee?
(b) the girls must include either Roberta or Priya,
but not both?

For part a), I got the answer 43680 by doing 14C3 x 16C2 and the answer is correct but however, for part b) the answer I got is 76440 by doing 14C3 x 15C2 x 2 but the answer is wrong. Please Help!

Comment: Who is Ana? Boy or girl?

Comment: she is a girl...

Comment: Your solution looks correct.  Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: The answer at the back of the book for part b) is 65520

Comment: In adding the cases where Roberta is included and when Priya is included, you have counted twice, the case where both are included. See the principle of inclusion and exclusion

Comment: So wouldn't it be 1x (15C2) + 1 x (15C2) = 210, but then when you do 14C3 x 210 the answer would be 76440 again.

Comment: @SulaimanMuzaffer You need to take your initial answer and subtract twice the number of ways to include both girls.

Comment: @Nicholas, please take a look at my answer.  If you still think inclusion-exclusion is required, post an answer showing the details.

Answer (score 3):

The OP's solution for part b) is entirely correct; the book must have made an error.

Requiring just one of the two girls Roberta and Priya to be on the committee is equivalent to splitting the students into *three* groups:  the $14$ boys, the $2$ girls Roberta and Priya, and the other $15$ girls, with the requirement that committee consist of $3$ members of the first group, $1$ member of the second group, and $2$ members of the third group.  The number of choices is thus

$${14\choose3}{2\choose1}{15\choose2}=364\cdot2\cdot105=76440$$

I'm not sure how the book got the answer $65520=364\cdot180$, unless it mistakenly did some sort of inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: You are right, though inclusion-exclusion also gives the same answer. I'd probably misread a few numbers earlier.

Comment: @Nicholas, I'm glad we're on the same page.  I am quite sure I've made far more mistakes than you, if only because I've had a few decades head start.  With luck, you'll catch up....